# Сортировка данных в ListBox исходя из выбора Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу убрать лишние данные из `listbox` при выборе в `Combobox`
Например: При нажатии на Realm 1 - удалить из `listbox` все `item`'ы, и оставить только те, `textbox` которых содержит только "realm1"

Код `ListBox`

```
<ListBox x:Name="List"
         Width="326"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Background="{x:Null}"
         BorderBrush="Transparent"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItem}"
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CharTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         SelectedIndex="0"
         Padding="0,5,0,0"
         VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CharTemplate">
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                 <Image x:Name="listPortait"
                        Width="80"
                        Height="50"
                        Source="{Binding ImageLink}"
                        Stretch="Fill" />
                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                             MaxWidth="174"
                             MaxHeight="100"
                             Margin="-5,25,0,25"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top">
                     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                         <TextBlock x:Name="nameBlock" 
                                    Text="{Binding Realms}"   
                                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap">
                             <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                 <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="#FF959595" />
                             </TextBlock.Foreground>
                         </TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>
                     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <TextBlock FontSize="14"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue=Title}"    
                                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                     </StackPanel>
                 </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.Resources>
 </ListBox>


private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbNews.Items.Add("All Realms");
    cbNews.Items.Add("Realm 1");
    cbNews.Items.Add("Realm 2");
    cbNews.Items.Add("Realm 3");
    cbNews.Items.Add("Realm 4");
    cbNews.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше кода

Comment: Можно уточнить: какого в точности типа `ExpressNews`?

Answer (score 1):

Что такое ExpressNewsSet, коллекция Realms - его свойство? Что нужно отобразить, список содержимого этой коллекции? Сложно что-то сказать, не понимая, как устроен ваш xml. Если так, то

```
combobox.ItemsSource = newsSet.Realms;
```

или

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding newsSet.Realms}"
```

Может быть стоит привязываться напрямую к XML с помощью [XMLDataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx)?